# Typescript error, unexpected ',' when fetching Geopoint

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I get a "Typescript error, unexpected ','" when i try to update location collection of a user field.

this is my code

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';



 updateDriverLocation(latitude, longitude, id:string)
 {
    return this.DriverCollection.doc(id).update({
          location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude); //this is where the error points at
        });
}
```

Please what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: My issue with firebase not defined was i was importing it wrongly. Corrected it.

Comment: you forgot the keyword `function` in `function updateDriverLocation`

Comment: Remove the semicolon, that line is part of a object not a statement

Comment: @dotconnor omg am such a moron. Silly mistake! Thanks

Comment: @dotconnor now i get a firebase not defined error. Any help?

Comment: how are you importing firebase?

Comment: @dotconnor already corrected it. Edited my question

Answer (score 2):

```
updateDriverLocation(latitude, longitude, id: string) {
  return this.DriverCollection.doc(id).update({
    location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
  });
}
```

Here you're sending in an object to the update function:

```
{
        location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
      }
```

An object property can't end with `;`

Instead the code should be:

```
updateDriverLocation(latitude, longitude, id: string) {
  return this.DriverCollection.doc(id).update({
    location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
  });
}
```

Comment: @PatrickObafemi Then I assume you have forgotten to include firebase. I'm not sure where you should be importing it. In an html file perhaps?

Comment: Imported it wrongly. Already corrected it in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code:

```
updateDriverLocation(latitude, longitude, id:string)
{
   return this.DriverCollection.doc(id).update({
      location: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
    });
}
```

Comment: You should explain why it is correct. Don't just say it is correct.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it is correct cos you do not add a semi colon after an object property.

Comment: @PatrickObafemi I know it is correct, but on SO, you should explain your reasoning. That is the whole point of SO, as it is basically a Wiki. If you looked up Thomas Edison on Wikipedia, and all it said was he was an inventor, Wikipedia wouldn't be very helpful now would it?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn my bad. I already explained why it is correct though. Thanks a lot